# Custom StructuredTextEditor not showing colour codes when opening html code.

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, eclipse-plugin, codehighlighter

I have this custom StructuredTextEditor that opens a customised HTML code in an eclipse plugin project. In earlier version, the codes were visible but ever since I ported it over to Eclipse Juno, compiled it and ran it, the editor doesn't show any codes in colour. Also, '**UNDO**' function doesn't work.

*What the page should look like:*

[image]

*What the page actually looks like:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The editor that I was using to display the contents of the **HTML** file should subclass **StructuredTextEditor** class instead of **StructuredTextEditorHTML** class. Furthermore, the editor can then be used for opening any other structured text files like jsp, xml, xsl, dtd etc.